# Is it possible to be connected to Chrome with one account but have another account set has my first account for Gmail (and Google)?

Tags: gmail

Is it possible to **be connected to Chrome with one account**
but have **another account** set has my **first account for Gmail (and Google)**?

I already know how to use several Google accounts for Chrome and switch between them,
and how to use several Google accounts for Gmail and switch between them,
but I couldn't find anything on the Web for my specific question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve a close result using the simple trick of **cusomizing Chrome's "New tab" setting**.

And to achieve this, I personnaly use the **extension** "[New Tab Redirect](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-redirect/icpgjfneehieebagbmdbhnlpiopdcmna)" (but you could also use "[Custom New Tab URL](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/custom-new-tab-url/mmjbdbjnoablegbkcklggeknkfcjkjia)", or "[New Tab Changer](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/new-tab-changer/occbjkhimchkolibngmcefpjlbknggfh)").

For your new tabs, assuming that you'd want to use the second account you connected with on Google, **specify this for the URL**: **https://www.google.com/?authuser=1** for Google's main page
(or https://mail.google.com/mail/u/1 for GMail ).

(If you'd want to use your third account, you would use, /?authuser=2 or /u/2, and so on.)

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. All you need to do is to open the Google account manager by clicking the profile picture at the top right of any Google service (not the browser), then click to sign out of all accounts.

The browser will show a message saying that the sync will be paused because you are signing out of the account that is linked to the browser, but just click continue. After that, the sync will show as paused, then log in to the account that you want to have as the primary one and then click in the profile picture of your browser to log into the account you will be using for the browser to resume the sync again. This time that account will be the primary for Chrome sync but a secondary account when accessing the Google services.

Comment: Hi Fernando, Your solution works, but unfortunately, if you close Chrome and then reopen it, the account for the browser becomes the primary account for the Google services again...

Comment: You are right. I didn't test the behavior after closing the browser. In that case the only workaround is to have separate profiles since Chrome will always take the profile from Chrome Sync as the primary one. It looks like it only works if you do not have Chrome Sync ON.